# Error with stremio installing (ENOENT)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, streaming

I have problems installing [Stremio](https://www.stremio.com/downloads#linux) via a guide on GitHub.

I am at the 2nd to last step of the [guide](https://github.com/Stremio/stremio-shell/blob/master/DEBIAN.md) (7th step), connecting to the streaming server.

The `server.js` file is in the `stremio-shell` map.

But I get this error code :

```
emile@UbuntuEmile:~/stremio-shell$ node server.js
hls executables located ->  { ffmpeg: null, ffsplit: null }
Using app path -> /home/emile/.stremio-server
Enabling casting...
EngineFS server started at http://127.0.0.1:11470
EngineFS HTTPS endpoint at https://local.strem.io:12470
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/emile/.stremio-server/localFiles'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/emile/.stremio-server/localFiles' }
```

I have already tried creating the filepath like in the error code but this still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a home/emile/.stremio-server/localFiles/ directory?

Comment: Yes, I made one and it just said that there was no such file in the directory